# ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dots')

Tags: rust, substrate

Error while running `npx @substrate/playground-cli`

[image]

Comment: I don't think the error is from that part of the code since your not trying to read the dots properties. My guess would be that the error is inside your spinner component where your trying to read that property.

Comment: Since cli is outdated, it won't work they said. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CLI is outdated, this version doesn't work anymore. The web version serves the same goal and should be more convenient.

Go to [docs.substrate.io/playground/](https://docs.substrate.io/playground/), choose a template and click 'Launch Playground'